# Unable to initialize SSL context during Wildfly 18 startup with Amazon JDK 1.8, and latest BC FIPS libraries for JCAJCE and TLS

Tags: java, ssl, wildfly

We are unable to successfully startup Wildfly 18 when the 1.8 Java Corretto JDK is configured with the latest BC FIPS libraries to support FIPS compliant AWS EC2 Linux based environments.

bc-fips-1.0.2.1.jar (also tried with bc-fips-1-0-2.jar)
bctls-fips-1.0.12.2.jar

The error appears to be related to the unsuccessful initialization of the Wildlfy SSL context during startup.  When the request to get context data is being issued - the BCJSSE provider does not appear have performed the context data initialization - and a null value for the context data results in the exception being thown.

Enabling FINEST level logging for both Wildfly and the BouncyCastle libraries does not provide any trace level information to confirm context initialization prior to when the error condition is reported.

--

```
2022-01-24 14:46:52,518 FINE  [org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.PropertyUtils] (MSC service thread 1-2) Boolean system property [org.bouncycastle.jsse.trustManager.checkEKU] defaulted to: true
2022-01-24 14:46:52,639 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.security.ssl-context.httpsSSLContext: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.security.ssl-context.httpsSSLContext: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)        
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)        
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)        
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SSLContext has not been initialized.
        at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLContextSpi.getContextData(ProvSSLContextSpi.java:877)
        at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLContextSpi.engineGetServerSessionContext(ProvSSLContextSpi.java:821)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getServerSessionContext(SSLContext.java:386)
        at org.wildfly.security.ssl.SSLContextBuilder.lambda$build$0(SSLContextBuilder.java:340)
        at org.wildfly.security.OneTimeSecurityFactory.create(OneTimeSecurityFactory.java:53)
        at org.wildfly.extension.elytron.SSLDefinitions$6.lambda$getValueSupplier$1(SSLDefinitions.java:1173)
        at org.wildfly.extension.elytron.TrivialService.start(TrivialService.java:53)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        ... 6 more
```

--

The JDK security providers are configured as following:

```
security.provider.1 = org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider
security.provider.2 = sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.3 = org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider fips:BCFIPS
security.provider.4 = sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.5 = sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.6 = com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.7 = sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.8 = com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.9 = org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
```

Also - with the same JDK provider settings and standalone.xml settings in place - Wildlfy startup is successful when the JDK is configured with an older set of BCFIPS jars.

bc-fips-1.0.1.jar
bctls-fips-1.0.8.jar

Any help or suggestions on why the Wildfly 18 server is no longer able to successfully initialize the HTTPS service SSL context during startup, when the JDK is configured with the newest set of BouncyCastle FIPS jars would be very much appreciated.

Thank you,

-Jayesh

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix to the problem of initializing the SSL context with Wildfly 18, when using updated BC FIPS libraries.

The fix is available in Wildfly 21.

https://github.com/wildfly-security/wildfly-elytron/commit/3d7375f5f61526a7b8c4046878adc68e6777b308